# magento checkout billing save returns error

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

i'm working with a magento website, when i fill the billing info on checkout and click on continute button. the save billing ajax response give this error

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'Mage_Chunit_Helper_Data' not found in <b>/home/boutique/public_html/app/Mage.php</b> on line <b>516</b><br />
```

so i cannot go to the next step.in the system log i can see this

```
 2014-01-16T13:44:48+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Chunit/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in 
    /home/boutique/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
    2014-01-16T13:44:48+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Chunit/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in 
    /home/boutique/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
    2014-01-16T13:44:48+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Chunit/Helper/Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/boutique/public_html/app/code/local:/home/boutique/public_html/app/code/
community:/home/boutique/public_html/app/code/core:/home/boutique/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/boutique/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

i disabled the all extension from admin and check but no luck, can anyone know how to find a solution for this issue
Thank You

Comment: look in your code for something like `helper('chunit')` and see if you find it in a theme template or block

Comment: thanks you mean on .phtml files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have disabled all extensions. Your code is asking for a helper from the Chunit extension which can't be found due to the fact that most likely that module is disabled.

You can try enabling your modules and also check if you have a Chunit helper file in

`app/code/[community/local]/[Companyname]/Chunit/Helper/Data.php`

Comment: i found that and i commented out that codes, problem solved, thanks